# Adobe Air - Distribute Windows executable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

What is the best way to distribute an AIR app (AIR 2.5) that is packed as a Windows executable (.exe) ?

2 questions that bother me:

- What happens if a user doesn't have the AIR runtime installed?
- Does the AIR update framework still work?

Thanks
Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flash Builder 4.6](http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/09/flex-and-flash-builder-4-6-and-pre-release.html) is supposed to generate packages, which require no previous installation of AIR.

The new feature is named **captive runtime**.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Does Flash Builder version 4.5 also can do it?

Comment: No, captive runtime comes as a new feature with 4.6. What you can do, is generate an installer application. As far as I know, this doesn't include the AIR runtime itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. when the user runs the .exe file, he should see an Adobe Air Installation Window, before installing the application
2. I don't know if it works, but there is a library which allows you to update your application even if you packed it as a Windows Executable file
   here it is the link to the project home http://code.google.com/p/nativeapplicationupdater/

Answer (score 0):

If the AIR runtime isn't installed, it *should* ask to download and install the runtime first.

If by AIR update framework, you mean the ApplicationUpdater* classes, then yes, they do